# Gutenberg withInstanceId. When to use it?

Tags: block-editor

The WordPress block API for Gutenberg has a `withInstanceId` [package](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/compose/src/with-instance-id).

They say,

> Some components need to generate a unique id for each instance. This
>   could serve as suffixes to element ID's for example. Wrapping a
>   component with withInstanceId provides a unique instanceId to serve
>   this purpose.

and show an example:

```
/**
 * WordPress dependencies
 */
import { withInstanceId } from '@wordpress/compose';

function MyCustomElement( { instanceId } ) {
    return (
        <div id={ `my-custom-element-${ instanceId }` }>
            content
        </div>
    );
}

export default withInstanceId( MyCustomElement );
```

It seems like it is just being used for html ids? As to not have duplicate id names? Is there any other usage for it? If i just export my component using `export default withInstanceId( MyCustomElement )` will the entire component have a unique id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generated `id` is added to the component's props. So it can be accessed through `this.props.instanceId` inside the component.

In the example you posted it is being used to assign a unique [id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) to the html element. However it can be used for custom logic inside react. Just as an example, you can assign each component an `id` and then save its data to the redux store, that way when you need to access the data from an element inside the store you can use its `id` to find it.

Comment: if you used instanceid for your block and make reusable component using it. it will ask to update reusable component event if you didn't change any content in adding new page. this will happen in WP 5.7.2

Answer (score 2):

You could use clientId to uniquely identify the block. clientId is available in props.

Something like this..

```
export function EditBlock({clientId, setAttributes} ) {
  
  // save clientId in attributes to make it available in Save
  return (
        <div id={ `my-custom-element-${ clientId }` }>
            content
        </div>
    ); 
}
```

No need for HOC.